# Oracle SQL trigger on update of column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a trigger for my table which automatically adds a published date based on when a certain flag is set to 'Y'

I don't have much experience with creating triggers but so far this is what i've got

```
  create or replace
  TRIGGER ADD_CREATE_DT 
  after UPDATE of approved ON articles 
  for each row
  BEGIN
  :new.create_dt := sysdate where approved = 'Y';
  END;
```

I get this error when updating the column

> trigger 'USER.ADD_CREATE_DT' is invalid and failed re-validation

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the WHEN clause:

```
create or replace
  TRIGGER ADD_CREATE_DT 
  after UPDATE of approved ON articles 
  for each row
  when (new.approved = 'Y')
  BEGIN
  :new.create_dt := sysdate;
  END;
```

Or use IF:

```
create or replace
  TRIGGER ADD_CREATE_DT 
  after UPDATE of approved ON articles 
  for each row
  BEGIN
  if :new.approved = 'Y' then
   :new.create_dt := sysdate;
  end if;
  END;
```

In this case, WHEN is more appropriate and efficient.

Comment: Thanks - couldn't get the 'WHEN' to work but the 'IF' works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

```
create or replace
  TRIGGER ADD_CREATE_DT 
  after UPDATE of approved ON articles 
  for each row
  BEGIN
    IF :NEW.approved = 'Y' THEN
      :new.create_dt := sysdate;
    END IF;
  END;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know What version of Oracle do you use?
In Oracle 10g I got the following error:

```
ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type
04084. 00000 -  "cannot change NEW values for this trigger type"
*Cause:    New trigger variables can only be changed in before row
           insert or update triggers.
*Action:   Change the trigger type or remove the variable reference.
```

It does not allow to change the field on AFTER triggers.

Comment: A `BEFORE` trigger definitely seems more appropriate in this case (where the column being updated belongs to the same table that the trigger is on).