# Track which columns were modified by an Update

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, audit-trail

How do I track the list of updated columns in a table

```
Table1
Name    Place    Email                    Id
John     US      john@gmail.com            1
Sam      US      sam@gmail.com             2
```

Now if I update Name,place columns for John and place,email for Sam like

```
Name     Place    Email                   Id
Johnny    UK      john@gmail.com           1
Sam       UK      sammy@gmail.com         2
```

I want to store the list of updated attributes in another table as following

```
Id       ListOfModifiedAttributes    Status     othercolumns
1        name,place                  success
2        place,email                 success
```

How to achieve the above in plsql.

Comment: Maintain an audit table for Table1 and use a  trigger to populate the values.

Comment: If you don't want to modify tables you could only observe specific columns with dedicated triggers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982052/oracle-sql-trigger-on-update-of-column. Very often only some changes are interesing. Perhaps 2 or 3 triggers do the job aswell.